# Secure UDFN click with microchip ATECC608A-TNGTLS to Google cloud iot core?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot, banana-pi

I am using microchip ATECC608A-TNGTLS with Mikroe Secure UDFN click. As far as i know its a click platform to authorize the device to google iot core. But i am not able to find any tutorial or example about how can i connect my Banana PI M4 to Google iot core using this platform?

I saw this example 
https://github.com/MicrochipTech/gcp-iot-core-examples/tree/master/boards/raspi
but i am quite confused about how can i get the keys out of that secure chip. Is there anyone who already did the same setup and can help me? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the answer.

First you need to install the python package cryptoauthtools.
There are alot of examples are present like creating a JWT from ATECC608A.

```
https://github.com/MicrochipTech/cryptoauthtools/tree/master/python/examples
```

Intitalise the lib, create a JWT for the login and then there is a pubsub example present on google cloud webpage to publish data on the gcp..

```
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/tutorials
```